# How to apply cache to spring oauth ClientDetailsService

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, ehcache

this is more an answer than a question - documenting it for other people that might look for this.

we are using Spring JdbcClientDetailsService and in current version 2.0.5 it produce more than 1 query per resource request/token request, and might cause some performance issue.
so we followed spring team advice (in release 2.0.3) to put cache on this service

we already had a ehcache setup so all i needed to do is several aop declarations.

**update**
now i was looking into putting a cache on the token and authentication objects as they are also queried a lot. but it turns out there is a problem with TokenStore.readAuthentication - i guess there is a problem with method overloading, cause one signature is spring and the other is token object.

i've tried something like this but it didn't work

```
<aop:advisor advice-ref="authByTokenIdAdvice" pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore.readAuthentication(String))"/>
```

anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Thanks for this post ! Could you please also show your ehcache setup ?

Comment: its simple as <cache name="OauthClientDetailsServiceCache" eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="200" overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

Comment: Thank you very much ! One more question - did it help you to solve the issue with accessToken performance ? Looks like I have a similar one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175068/spring-rest-oauth2-resource-server-and-performance-issue

Comment: We don't have this problem - i think it can help with access token but  if you have a cluster - you will need distributed cache so tokens will be synced in the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

This is for caching the client details.eviction is only relevant in non cluster environments, in cluster environment - i suggest to override client services and send a message to the other node to clear the cached item.

```
<cache:advice id="cacheClientsAdvice" cache-manager="cacheManager">
            <cache:caching cache="OauthClientDetailsServiceCache">
                <cache:cacheable method="loadClientByClientId" key="#clientId"/>
            </cache:caching>
        </cache:advice>
        <cache:advice id="cacheEvictClient" cache-manager="cacheManager">
            <cache:caching cache="OauthClientDetailsServiceCache">

                <cache:cache-evict method="removeClientDetails" key="#clientId" before-invocation="false"/>
            </cache:caching>
        </cache:advice>

        <!-- apply the cacheable behavior to all ClientDetailsService interface methods -->
        <aop:config>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="cacheClientsAdvice" pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService.*(..))"/>
        </aop:config>
        <aop:config>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="cacheEvictClient" pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientRegistrationService.*(..))"/>
        </aop:config>
```